# regarding showMessageDialog box in Java

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm having problems with the `showMessageDialog` method.

I have the following code in my program

When I run the program and a diaglog with NamedPlace pops up

```
if (place instanceof NamedPlace) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Named Place");
    return;
}
```

According to the code above I get the message dialog box as expected but when I click on the OK button I get two `OK` on the map. This is what confuses me. Why do I get them? And how do I get rid of it?

I have been sitting for a long time trying to understand this but I still do not understand how to remove these OK which comes up even I do not have written any code for them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please 1) Take the [tour] 2) Read [ask] 3) Post a proper [mre], the error might be in the code not shown here. 4) There's no need to end your post with "regards Mosa" because this isn't an email and we already know your username

Comment: You're not including enough code. We need to see the code around the snippet you posted in order to see the context within which you are working. The problem isn't the way you're generating a message dialog, but rather, the way you're calling that code. You're also going to have to explain what you mean by "I get two OK on the map." We've never seen your program before, so you cannot expect us to know what map you're talking about or what "two OK" means. Two OK buttons? Two labels that say OK? What, exactly, do you mean?

Comment: Sorry not to be accurate in my previous question. I tried to attach two files which shows map and OK buttons. both were imagefiles. But i didnot succed to attach the image file. How to attach image files in the question?

Comment: You were not asked for image files. You were asked for code in the form of an [mre]. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code you provide and see the same problem.